# Does changing the residence permit, to Blue Card would help me for migration to Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, immigration

I got my MSc. Software engineering in Estonia. When i graduated, i received a new residence permit for 5 years (which is not a Blue Card). Generally, I received my residence permit because, I got a degree in an Estonian University.

Now, I wish to move to Germany. But, from time to time HRs contact me in Linkdin, and Xing, and it seems that, some companies are not willing to hire someone who does not have a Blue Card.

I asked the police about changing the type of my residence permit to Blue Card, and they warned me in case i get a Blue Card, i should change my card whenever i change my company.

My questions are:

1. Why lack of Blue card is an obstacle for hiring process?

I mean, as long as, I have a valid contract, I might be able to apply for a new Blue Card, and it should not take more than a month or so. So, why the companies are so scared of this problem?

2. Do you think, changing the residence permit, to Blue Card would help me for migration?

I mean, even if i have a Blue Card for my current company in Estonia, when i join a new company in Germany then i have to change the card again. Does that mean, having a Blue card is not helpful? Or does not make a big difference?